# Suggest add the search engine to firefox when user is in site

Tags: html, firefox, url, search-engine

I was at duckduckgo and wanted to add the search engine field to my browser,

Usually you had to search in the browser utility, but I was surprised when I saw the browser already detecting it.

[image]

How can I get my site's search to show up automatically like this?

Please note:

I'm not looking (now) to implement the auto-suggest feature, i am just trying to get the service saved in the browser (exact same behaviour with stackoverflow+firefox)

-EDIT-

Tried the code I found on their site, wich matchs with the opensearch documentation:

1)

```
    <link title="your service name" type="application/opensearchdescription + xml " rel="
search " href="/opensearch.xml ">
```

2) the xml file: /opensearch.xml

```
<OpenSearchDescription>
     <ShortName>DuckDuckGo</ShortName>
     <Description>Search DuckDuckGo (SSL)</Description>
     <InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
     <LongName>DuckDuckGo Search (SSL)</LongName>
     <Image width="16" height="16">http://duckduckgo.com/favicon.ico</Image>
     <Url type="text/html" method="get" template="https://duckduckgo.com/?q={searchTerms}"/>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

But with my domain name and URL, and firefox is not detecting the service (the same way as in the picture), what am i missing?

Comment: If anyone whant to edit and re-tag the question i will be very wellcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a look at your site (funcook.com) and:

1) You have to remove all the spaces in the type attribute of the link tag:

```
<link title="Funcook" type="application/opensearchdescription + xml" rel="search" href="http://funcook.com/opensearch.xml" />
```

becomes:

```
<link title="Funcook" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" rel="search" href="http://funcook.com/opensearch.xml" />
```

2) You have to use the proper namespace in opensearch.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OpenSearchDescription>
[...]
```

becomes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
[...]
```

Comment: The browser detects now the service :D but not the favicon, the url is fine. any idea?

Comment: Try moving your favicon to the website's root. You must also convert it to the ICO format. So your URL should be: `http://funcook.com/favicon.ico`

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, Firefox, IE & Chrome are capable of detecting sites that implement the [OpenSearch Standard](http://www.opensearch.org/Home).

Basically, you will provide an XML OpenSearch Description Document on your site that looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
  <ShortName>Web Search</ShortName>
  <Description>Use Example.com to search the Web.</Description>
  <Tags>example web</Tags>
  <Contact>admin@example.com</Contact>
  <Url type="application/rss+xml" 
       template="http://example.com/?q={searchTerms}&amp;pw={startPage?}&amp;format=rss"/>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

...and link to it in the `<head>` of your site like so:

```
<link rel="search" 
  type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" 
  href="http://www.example.com/search.src" 
  title="Add Example.Com Search" />
```

The comments in [this lifehacker.com article](http://lifehacker.com/228008/detect-firefox+compatible-search-enginesin-firefox) (you will need to select 'All' to see the comments) seem to address how to implement it on your own site with references to Facebook's implementation. Looking around, it seems [quite a few major reference sites implement this functionality](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/opal/archive/2007/11/04/some-opensearch-sites-for-reference.aspx).

Comment: the lifehacker link only points that what i am asking is posible. I will look into the opensearch standard. But it would be great to find a specific example. thanks!

Comment: It's in the comments! Click the all button to see the discussion. It looks like it's specified via a `<link/>` in the `<head>`

Comment: So it should be the <link/> pointing the json file that contains this? http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/Extensions/Suggestions/1.1#Example_2

Comment: Um...not exactly. From what I can see, it looks like you will be linking an XML file per http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/1.1/Draft_5 . The JSON response you are looking at is for auto-complete suggestions.

Comment: I am not really interested (for now) in the auto-complete suggestions. Only to get the service saved in the browser (exact same behaviour with stackoverflow+firefox)

Comment: Right. So that link I just provided is the spec you should be following. Click the links in the facebook `<link>` tags on the lifehacker article above to see how they format their definition xml file.

Comment: Tried with both steps but it seems not to be detected by firefox (http://funcook.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Well,

i just thought, why not check their code?

two steps:

1) a  pointing a xml file

```
    <link title="your service name" type="application/opensearchdescription + xml " rel="
search " href=" / opensearch_ssl.xml ">
```

2) the xml file: /opensearch_ssl.xml

```
<OpenSearchDescription>
     <ShortName>DuckDuckGo</ShortName>
     <Description>Search DuckDuckGo (SSL)</Description>
     <InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
     <LongName>DuckDuckGo Search (SSL)</LongName>
     <Image width="16" height="16">http://duckduckgo.com/favicon.ico</Image>
     <Url type="text/html" method="get" template="https://duckduckgo.com/?q={searchTerms}"/>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

And that seems to be it, will test and mark as acepted